# how to replace a single variable of multi element NSArray in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsarray

I am struggling to update a single variable in an array create by Structs.

```
struct CurrentPolicyItems {
    var id:Int
    var currentInsured:String
    var currentPremium:String
    var currentXDate:String
    var typeID:Int
    var productID:Int
    var buildingID:Int
    var noteID:Int
    var isUsed:Int
    var isTemp:Int
}
struct CurrentPolicyTemp {
    static var array = [CurrentPolicyItems]()
}
```

When I close a class, I need to change all var "isTemp" from 1 to 0.  Not all elements are used, so I need to filter them before any updates.  I believe I am close, just can't get the last bit.

I have tried:

```
    if let items = CurrentPolicyTemp.array.firstIndex( where: { $0.isTemp == 1}) {
    CurrentPolicyTemp.array[items].isTemp = 0
    }
```

However, as we all know, this will only update a single element.  I have tried .filter, but hit the error of "item is immutable" error.

Help please.

Comment: Why are you using an Int instead of a Bool?

Comment: Btw you need to iterate all elements anyway so just set all to false `CurrentPolicyTemp.array.indices.map { CurrentPolicyTemp.array[$0].isTemp = 0 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.`firstIndex` iterates through a loop to obtain the FIRST index that matches the following criteria. You simply take this a step back and do this yourself...

```
for (index, item) in CurrentPolicyTemp.array.enumerated() where item.isTemp == 1 {
    CurrentPolicyTemp.array[index].isTemp = 0
}
```

Or on a simpler terms:

```
for (index, item) in CurrentPolicyTemp.array.enumerated() {
    if(item.isTemp == 1) {
        CurrentPolicyTemp.array[index].isTemp = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend a `for` loop with a `where` clause as filter

```
for (index, element) in CurrentPolicyTemp.array.enumerated() where element.isTemp == 1 {
    CurrentPolicyTemp.array[index].isTemp = 0
}
```

Comment: thats clever :)

Comment: I think it is much easier to simply iterate the indices and set them all to 0

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, if the `Int` is actually a `Bool` but who knows...

Comment: Thanks All for your help

Answer (score 1):

Arguements passed to all the functions in swift are readonly (immutable in nature) unless the argument is marked with inout. So when you use `filter` $0 is immutable in nature so you cant simply set it to `$0.isTemp = 0`

what you can do is

```
        CurrentPolicyTemp.array = CurrentPolicyTemp.array.map({if $0.isTemp == 1 {
            var newPolicy = $0
            newPolicy.isTemp = 0
            return newPolicy
        }
        return $0 })
```

What am doing here is rather than trying to mutate the `$0` I create a new copy of $0 and mutate it instead.